# HTTPKit gives ProtocolException: "No status" for a Let's Encrypt site

Tags: clojure, http-kit

I'm trying to retrieve a URL. At the time of writing: https://upvote.pub/

Using the `java.net.URL`, I can retrieve this fine:

```
=> (count (slurp (.openStream (java.net.URL. "https://upvote.pub/"))))
44353
```

Ditto clj-http:

```
=> (count (:body (clj-http.client/get "https://upvote.pub/")))
44353
```

But when I use HTTPKit I run into problems:

```
=> @(http/get "https://upvote.pub/")
{:opts {:method :get, :url "https://upvote.pub/"}, :error #error {
 :cause "No status"
 :via
 [{:type org.httpkit.ProtocolException
   :message "No status"
   :at [org.httpkit.client.RespListener onCompleted "RespListener.java" 126]}]
 :trace
 [[org.httpkit.client.RespListener onCompleted "RespListener.java" 126]
  [org.httpkit.client.Request finish "Request.java" 51]
  [org.httpkit.client.HttpClient doRead "HttpClient.java" 156]
  [org.httpkit.client.HttpClient run "HttpClient.java" 426]
  [java.lang.Thread run "Thread.java" 745]]}}
```

This site uses Let's Encrypt. However, other Let's Encrypt sites seem to work:

```
=> (-> "https://letsencrypt.org/" http/get deref :body count)
21490
```

The certificate has different properties, but it's from the same authority.

Furthermore, if I include `:insecure? true`, the error still happens.

I thought this might be related to [this HTTPS + proxy bug](https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit/issues/280), as the symptoms are similar and Google App Engine seems to be load-balancing the site. However, this fix was rolled into [release 2.2.0](https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit/releases/tag/2.2.0).

Is this a bug with HTTP-Kit? Can I work round it?

- openjdk version "1.8.0_92-internal"
- Clojure version 1.8.0
- http-kit version "2.2.0"

Comment: I think this is related to SNI, although the error presented seems to be  different to other SNI bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was caused by SNI (Server Name Identification). I used  HTTP Kit version “2.3.0-alpha5” and followed [this blog post](https://medium.com/@kumarshantanu/using-server-name-indication-sni-with-http-kit-client-f7d92954e165). It now works.